# Sort matrix elements around the diagonal

Tags: algorithm, sorting, matrix

I am looking for an algorithm that can sort the rows of a matrix so that the elements will cumulate around the diagonal.
I will have a square matrix (around 80 rows/ columns) containing only the values 0 and 1. There are algorithms that sort the rows in a way that most of the elements with the value 1 are below the diagonal. 
I need an algorithm that sort to minimize the mean distance of the elements to the diagonal.
Like so:
from:

```
0 1 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
```

to:

```
1 1 0
0 1 0
1 0 1
```

Since I am not familiar with this topic I hope that someone can help me. I am not looking for a complete solution. The name of such algorithm if it exists or a pseudo code would be sufficient.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a more efficient way, but you could treat this problem as an [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) (trying to assign each row to a diagonal element).

This can be done in three steps:

1) Create a new matrix M where each entry M(i,j) contains the cost of assigning row i of your input matrix to the diagonal element j. For your example this matrix will be the following (average distance to the diagonal element):

```
1   0   1
1   1   1
1  0.5 1.5
```

Example: `M(0,0) = 1` is the average distance when assigning row 0 of the input matrix (`0 1 0`) to the diagonal element positioned at 0.

2) Run an algorithm to find the best assignment (e.g., [hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)). This will give you an optimal 1:1 matching between rows and columns minimizing the sum of cost in the matrix.

```
The result will be the elements (0,1), (1,2) and (2,0)
```

3) Rearrange your input matrix using this knowledge. So

```
row 0 -> row 1
row 1 -> row 2
row 2 -> row 0
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution makes absolutely sense - especially for my application.

Comment: @spaceEngineer glad that I could help. Consider upvoting or accepting answers that helped you.